# Azure function v 2.0 and azure service bus trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I try to trigger my function using azure service bus but I getting error:

> ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp: The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger'
>   are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding
>   extension is installed.

and warnning:

> No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods
>   public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage,
>   ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration
>   method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
>   builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

How should I register those extensions ?

[image: screen with my Nuget :]

Comment: Do you have this NuGet package installed? `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus`

Comment: yes, In version 3.0.1

Comment: And you have the connection to the service bus in your `local.settings.json` file and the name is correct?

Comment: local.settings.json seems to be ok : {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "serviceBusConnection": "="
  }
}

Comment: Is there an actual value for your service bus? You need to have a service bus instance available for connection

Comment: connection string is ok

Comment: @user656822 Could you remove your project references and try to run a standalone Function projects?

Comment: I have the same error even when i start  new project

Comment: @user656822 Could you provide the content of the following files? 1) {your project}/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/bin/extensions.json and 2) {your project}/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp/function.json

Comment: I dont have extensions.json file :)

Comment: That could be part of the problem. Can you try a rebuild of your project and check again?